# Concat a line with a string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am using a bash script to read from a csv file :

```
#!/bin/bash
b=".html"
declare -a files=()
while read line
do
   files+=("${line}${b}")
done < all_fr.csv
echo "${files[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n'
```

the variable `$line` contains an `ID` and i want to add `.html` on every ID, i tried the code above and it give me an output like this:

```
.html77
.html92
.html98
.html00
.html97
.html27
.html31
.html39
.html44
.html45
.html60
```

My IDs are long exemple : 43567

when i do store in the list $line the output is good no problem, the problem appears when i add `.html`

PS: i tried to use a variable : `a= $line.html` but didn't work for me

A picture on my csv file from windows:
[image: csv file]

Comment: Does your input file contain `\n` line endings, or `\r\n`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell \n

Comment: What is the picture above?  You describe it as `A picture of my csv file from windows`, which strongly makes me suspect it does not have unix line endings.  Show the output of `xxd all_fr.csv | head`

Comment: How sure are you? It totally looks like your file uses `\r\n` line endings *and* you said you are using Windows (which uses `\r\n` by default). Use `dos2unix all_fr.csv` to convert the file.

Comment: @Socowi yeah ur right i did some search and it's \r\n excuses, about windows it's to show the file nothing more

Comment: @WilliamPursell the output: 00000000: 3135 3434 370d 0a31 3534 3534 0d0a 3135  15447..15454..15
00000010: 3435 370d 0a31 3534 3631 0d0a 3135 3436  457..15461..1546
00000020: 320d 0a31 3534 3633 0d0a 3135 3437 300d  2..15463..15470.
00000030: 0a31 3534 3732 0d0a 3135 3437 330d 0a31  .15472..15473..1
00000040: 3534 3734 0d0a 3135 3437 380d 0a31 3534  5474..15478..154
00000050: 3739 0d0a 3135 3438 300d 0a31 3534 3835  79..15480..15485
00000060: 0d0a 3135 3439 320d 0a31 3534 3933 0d0a  ..15492..15493..
00000070: 3135 3439 340d 0a31 3534 3935 0d0a 3135  15494..15495..15

Comment: `0d0a` is `\r\n`

Comment: @Socowi yes it did work thank you man, could you please post your answer so i can accept it!!

Comment: Note that you don't really need `dos2unix`.  You could also just add a `tr -d '\r'` to your pipe.